# Add ssh user on aws using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

Looking for a python script solution(ideas) in order to create any given ssh user after provisioning an ec2 instance. I am able to launch ec2 via boto.run_instances, however, not sure how to create ssh user after launching.

Comment: This doesn't look like a specific question.

Comment: IAM Roles can upload SSH public keys and manage account password policies, take a look here: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.upload_ssh_public_key

Comment: Seems using public-key is better than using passwords, IF I didn't miss your question.

Comment: @d33tah Looking for a python script solution(ideas) in order to create a given ssh user after provisioning ec2 instance. I am able to launch ec2 via boto.run_instances, however, not sure how to create ssh user after launching.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your requirement is:

- **Launch** an Amazon EC2 instance via `boto.run_instances`
- When the instance has launched, automatically **create a new user** on the instance and insert their public key into `/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys` such that the user can then login to the instance

You could use a User Data startup script to:

- Create the new user
- Store their public key in `/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys`

The tricky part is passing the public key into the script. You could include it raw in the script, or download it from Amazon S3.

For details, see:

- [Managing User Accounts on Your Linux Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-users.html)
- [How to add new users to EC2 and give SSH Key access](http://www.ampedupdesigns.com/blog/show?bid=44)
- [Running Commands on Your Linux Instance at Launch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html)